# Hive command for finding the data nodes on which a query was run

Tags: hive

Can somebody help me with a hive command to find the data nodes on which a aprticular hive query was run.

For eg- Select * from mytable;

ran on which data nodes in my hadoop cluster having only hive.

Answer (score 0):

1. datanode is only for storage.what you really want is `which mr node is running  the sql`
2. hive transform the sql to normal MR jobs.So you can find your sql job at `jobtracker(MR1)` or `resoucemanager(yarn)` web interface

Comment: Thanks for the reply.....actually I want to get this information for each query and hence am looking for a command which can be run on hadoop-hive command line